# Rails helper function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Disclaimer: I'm a rails n00b. I'm playing around with a simple helper function that isn't doing what I want it to do.

- I have a model called 'webform' with a few text fields (name, address, etc)
- I'm trying to use a helper function to test an if statement (i.e. 'is the :address == '10')
- Here's the helper function

  ```
  def webforms_helper
    if :address == 10
      print "Address is 10"
    else
      print "Address is not 10"
    end   
  end
  ```
- In my 'show' view, I have incorporated the helper function `<%= webforms_helper %>`
- I load the web app, get no errors -- though, it doesn't print out 'Address is 10' or 'Address is not 10'
- I've also had no success using puts (and checking the console) instead of print
- Any thoughts? I apologize for the novice question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a proper helper would look like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def myformchecker(ahash)
     if ahash[:address] == '10'
        return 'Address is 10'
     end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper: application
  ...
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= myformchecker(params) %>
```

So if the view were rendered in response to a form submit,  and the form has the following:

```
<%= text_field_tag :address %>
```

And when the user filled out the form and put the string '10' as the address,  'Address is 10' would be generated in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your exercise is not very clear, but something like this...

```
def webforms_helper 
  if :address == 10 
    print "Address is 10" 
  else 
    print "Address is not 10" 
  end
end
```

will never print out anything to a Rails view for 1 reason, You're using puts and print methods, These two will output to the console. You must return the string itself, Do it like this...

```
def webforms_helper 
  if :address == 10 
    "Address is 10" 
  else 
    "Address is not 10" 
  end
end
```

I understand you are doing a simple demo, but nevertheless it's a good idea to pass arguments to a Helper. That's what you'll do 99% of the time..

```
def webforms_helper(address)
  if address == 10 
    #return something meaningful as string to the view
  else 
    #return something meaningful as string to the view too.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the information to the helper so it can make the decision for you.

```
# app/views/webforms/show.html.erb
<%= webforms_helper(address) %>

# app/helpers/webform_helper.rb
module WebformHelper
  def webforms_helper(address)
    if address == 10
      "Address is 10"
    else
      "Address is not 10"
    end
  end
end
```

I would also heartily recommend finding a good book ([Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)) or tutorial ([Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)) if you're just starting out with Rails.

Comment: Thanks Jason -- appreciate it.